# is there a version of SmartAdmin/Sb-Admin based on angular-meteor?

Tags: angularjs, angular-meteor, smartadmin

I'm one of these people who learns best by looking at examples

I've been searching through different variants of wrapbootstrap's SmartAdmin/Sb-Admin.

Found one based just on Angular. Also, found one based just on Meteor

Could not find one based on both (i.e. one, using angular-meteor bridge)

Wonder of anyone have come across such a breed

Comment: Would love to know if there is one too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little late to the party, but for purposes of looking at different code samples on WrapBootstrap, how about Inspinia? It now seems to have both Meteor and Angular versions.

Project: https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/inspinia-responsive-admin-theme-WB0R5L90S

App Versions: http://webapplayers.com/inspinia_admin-v2.5/package.html